# return n indices of non-identical nearest neighbor vectors

Tags: algorithm, search, vector, nearest-neighbor

In a set of D dimension vectors, the nearest neighbor algorithm can efficiently acquire the n nearest neighbors for each vector in the entire set.

However, in such set, if there are multiple identical vectors, the nearest neighbor algorithm will return the identical vectors as the nearest vectors first. This makes sense, because the identical vectors are always closer to each other than the non-identical vectors.

But is there a algorithm just like nearest neighbor search, that does not take the identical vectors into account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need a different algorithm to achieve this. It is much simpler to remove the duplicates from the input data before running the standard algorithm.

Comment: There would be a problem with that, because for my case, I only concern about the duplicates within the current vector. Suppose I have point A and A' at the same location, but B at different location, when we check the distance from B to A and A', I would like to designate that there are 2 nearest neighbors. When we check A with A' and B, I want A to ignore A' in this case. Therefore, doing what you suggest will remove this information which I require.

Comment: @Karl You can still associate the whole list of duplicates with its single representation that will be passed to the algorithm. Alternatively, filter the duplicates at the output of the algorithm, only from cases listed as neighbours of another identical vector.